# Can I sent the same OTP in SMS and in Email using Authy?

Tags: twilio, authy

We want to provide an option to end user so that the user can get 2FA code in both way(in email and in SMS at same time)? Is it possible to send the same OTP via email as well as SMS at same time in Authy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Each different application/method of OTP delivery with Authy is assigned a different secret and generates different codes. So you cannot send the same code over email and SMS at the same time.

However, if you send two different OTP codes to your user, then either of them will work when they input the code and you verify it against the API.

Comment: Yes, I tested both code are validating the user. Thanks:)